# crashlytics keeps registering exception after code removed

Tags: android, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

This problem sounds really weird and it looks is somehow my mistake but isn't

I use crashlytics to keep logs and track exception of the usage of my app

for that i created a lib in the log4j interface which simple calls the crashlytics methods for log events.

On the first version of my lib i add an extra `Crashlytics.logException()` to every `logger.error()` in my code. After using it for a while i noticed that this behavior wasn't what i want and I removed the `Crashlytics.logException()`

BUT CRASHLYTICS KEPT SHOWING EXCEPTIONS ON THAT

I'm really confuse with that and for a long time i thought i was doing something wrong, but after debuging the code thousands of times i came to think that there is something beyond what i see

there is no metion of `Crashlytics.logException()` in my code, and somehow i still manage to see many errors in my crashlytics dashboard

can someone help me with that?
what events might generate a non-fatal issue on crashlytics dashboard

attach:
- https://pastebin.com/Rbu1ySpd this is the core class of my log lib
- whenever i want to log an even i do `logger.log("something");' in a very log4j way

Comment: Are you sure the exceptions are on the latest version, and not from users on the previous version?

Comment: yes because crashlytics show the version of the app throwing the exception